# Make Ubuntu remember the printer configuration

Tags: 17.10, printing, epson

In Artful, I have downloaded the printer drivers for my Epson WF-2660, connected via WiFi, and I can get it to work.

However, whenever I turn on my printer, Ubuntu auto-configures it incorrectly (it uses the wrong driver). If I go into the cups admin screen and configure it there, it works.

The problem: Whenever I turn off my computer and printer, Ubuntu (and cups) forgets about it. I thus have to re-configure it every time I want to use it because the autoconfiguration does not work and it forgets the printer I manually configured.

How do I make Ubuntu remember the configured Wifi printers over restarts, even if they may be momentarily not available?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The service for deleting and adding printers is done by avahi. That service is a bit too aggressive for me. I too kept getting a  printer connected to a "null" device on every boot.

See `/etc/avahi/avahi-daemon.conf` and change

```
use-ipv4=yes
use-ipv6=yes
```

to

```
use-ipv4=no
use-ipv6=no
```

and it will no longer scan for hardware on boot leaving your printers as you created them.

Answer (score 1):

Okay, I got it to work reliably: Instead of using the Ubuntu printer configuration tool I used the browser to go to http://localhost:631 where cups' built-in admin tool resides. I configured the printer there and now it stays configured. It still automatically adds an auto-configured, non-functioning, second printer whenever I turn on the printer, but if I just ignore that, I can print. An ideal solution, however, this is not.

Comment: And you still accepted my answer?  <3

Comment: Yes, well, my version works, but I still get the wrongly configured printer auto-added and have to choose the correct one every time I print. With the avahi configured less aggressively, I can now just print.